# How do I use cl_amd_offline_devices to compile a kernel for a specific GPU?

Tags: opencl, cross-compiling, amd-gpu, dynamic-compilation

I want to compile an OpenCL kernel for a certain AMD GPU - which is not available on my machine -, so that later I'm able to just load and run it when that GPU is present.

I've read this question here on SO:

[Offline compilation for AMD and NVIDIA OpenCL Kernels without cards installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12791527/1593077)

And the answer suggesting I create the OpenCL context with `CL_CONTEXT_OFFLINE_DEVICES_AMD`. Ok, I can do that. But what then? In AMD's OpenCL Programming User Guide, it says:

> A.8.6 `cl_amd_offline_devices`
>   To generate binary images offline, it is necessary to access the compiler for every
>   device that the runtime supports, even if the device is currently not installed on the system. When, during context creation, `CL_CONTEXT_OFFLINE_DEVICES_AMD` is passed in the context properties, all supported devices, whether online or offline, are reported and can be used to create OpenCL binary images.

ok, but how exactly? I'm assuming I'd need to call `clCompileProgram()` or `clBuildProgram()`, right? How do I set the device list for it to the device I like?

Answer (score 2):

As you assumed, you start with the usual `clCompileProgram()` and `clBuildProgram()`.

Next you can use `clGetProgramInfo()` with `CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES` to get the sizes for your buffer allocations, and a second time with `CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES` to get the actual binary images of the program.

This image can then be used with `clCreateProgramWithBinary()` instead of `clCreateProgramWithSource()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So, I need to go through all the devices to pick the one I want, and then use that index to get the size and the pointer to the compiled binary, and write that to a file? Ok, that sounds doable. I don't suppose you have a link to an example program doing this?

Comment: Sorry, no example at hand, but you can basically use any OpenCL Hello-World, and e.g., quickly modify it into two versions - one that creates the binaries and exits, and one that loads them instead of the source. Good luck. :-)